# Android Camera2 take picture while processing frames

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using Camera2 API to create a Camera component that can scan barcodes and has ability to take pictures during scanning. It is kinda working but the preview is flickering - it seems like previous frames and sometimes green frames are interrupting realtime preview.

My code is based on Google's Camera2Basic. I'm just adding one more `ImageReader` and its surface as a new output and target for `CaptureRequest.Builder`. One of the readers uses JPEG and the other YUV. Flickering disappears when I remove the JPEG reader's surface from outputs (not passing this into `createCaptureSession`).

There's quite a lot of code so I created a gist: [click](https://gist.github.com/aalices/1f88844762150b36aa4b3790fdc56b91) - Tried to get rid of completely irrelevant code.

Comment: `Thanks in advance!` You will certainly not get help if you think you can thank in advance. We are not in for that.

Comment: You wrote you are working with Nexus 5. Which ROM do you use?

Comment: Actually tested this on two Nexuses 5, one is using Android 5.1 and the other 6.0. No rooting at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever struggles with this. There is table in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#createCaptureSession(java.util.List%3Candroid.view.Surface%3E,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) showing that if there are 3 targets specified, the YUV ImageReader can use images with maximum size equal to the preview size (maximum 1920x1080). Reducing this helped!

Answer (score 1):

Is the device you're testing on a [LEGACY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY)-level device?

If so, any captures targeting a JPEG output may be much slower since they can run a precapture sequence, and may briefly pause preview as well.

But it should not cause green frames, unless there's a device-level bug.

Comment: It is a Nexus 5, so no - not a LEGACY device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Assuming that you configure your preview to feed the ImageReader with YUV frames (because you could also put JPEG there, check it out), like so:

```
mImageReaderPreview = ImageReader.newInstance(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);
```

You can process those frames inside your OnImageAvailable listener:

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image mImage = reader.acquireNextImage();
    if (mImage == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {

// Do some custom processing like YUV to RGB conversion, cropping, etc.

        mFrameProcessor.setNextFrame(mImage));
        mImage.close();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
}
```